# Blocking spaces ASP MVC and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to validate the code that users enter in my view. I want it to be MAJ and only letters and numbers. So no *"*"/(!/ or spaces. Everything works just fine except for the spaces...

Here's the code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @onkeydown = "onKeyDown(this);", @class = "input-visual-helper form-control", placeholder = @MyProject.Resources.home.ActivationCode })


            <script type="text/javascript">
            function onKeyDown(a) {
                var charCode = (a.which) ? a.which : event.keyCode

                setTimeout(function () {
                    a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
                }, 1);

                return ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57));
            }
        </script>
```

I did a console.log of the condition in the return and it logs false when I type the space (code 32). I even tried doing if(charCode ==32) return false. Still not working... The interface keeps doing a space in the textbox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is not a straight answer to your question but have you considered using a plug-in, such as this one: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ ?

Comment: Yeah... I wanted to keep things as simple as possible :S Thanks for the quick answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        $("#jam").keydown(function (e) {
             if (e.keyCode == 32) { 
               return false; 
             }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<input id="jam"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Something like this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#targetElement").keydown(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 32) { 
           return false; 
         }
    });
 </script>
```

https://jsbin.com/didohiloni/1/edit

For the MVC textbox you would append `new { id = "youid" }` in there

Comment: @Helpha no problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a complete version of the code

the control :

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.Code, new { @onkeydown= "onKeyDown(this)",  @id = "bindingCode", @class = "input-visual-helper form-control", placeholder = @Resources.home.Code })


 <script type="text/javascript">
            //No spaces and no special characters
            $(document).on('keypress', '#bindingCode', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                    return false;
                }
                var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Z0-9]+$");

                var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                key = key.toUpperCase();
                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
          //  All Letters in maj
            function onKeyDown(a) {
                var charCode = a.which;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
                }, 1);

            }
        </script>
```